# Why can I write to C# get-init property via XAML binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, c#-9.0

**Why can I write to C# `init` property when I bind to it?**

I tried the following code expecting *I cannot bind `TestRecordProp.Name`* since I thought I cannot update a `get-init` property after initialization.

```cs
public record TestRecord {
    public string Name { get; init; }
}

public class MyViewModel {
    public TestRecord TestRecordProp { get; init; } = new() { Name = "name" };
}
```

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding TestRecordProp.Name}" />
```

But, what surprised me, **I could edit the `TextBox` and the `Name` was updated.**

Why I could do this? Do I have to make controls read-only to prevent users from editing `init` properties?

---

I confirmed that when I edit `Name` in the `TextBox`, accessors are called in the following order:

1. `Name.init`
2. `TestRecordProp.get`
3. `Name.get`

So I guess the binding is setting values to `TestRecord.Name`, instead of creating a new instance of `TestRecord` class.

Comment: The other way around would be more unexpected, since strings also immutable.

Comment: Records aren't immutable by default https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record

Comment: Thanks @Andy for information, this article was also informative for me: https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/csharp-9-record-type.

Comment: Now I understood that records are not immutable by default, but my question is not solved. I rename this thread and continue.